# Issues occured when adopted the VB or VB.NET project

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, vb6

I am sorry about my lacking of VB knowledge(I am not a VB or .net developer), I adopted a very old and simple plug-in software, which probably was wrote by VB or VB.NET, the source code includes the files with the flowing suffix.

```
.dsx; .frm; .frx; msi; ,res; .sln; .vbp; .wip; .Dsr; .cls; .frm;
```

Here is the content of .sln file:

```
Microsoft Visual Studio Solution File, Format Version 1.00
Project("{73393D18-DAC4-11D1-88FC-0000F8064EBB}") = "Agile Plugin", "AgilePlugin.wip", "    {17DC5F11-9B32-47FE-9F12-71923EC1C0DC}"
EndProject
Global
GlobalSection(LocalDeployment) = postSolution
    StartupProject = {00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000}
EndGlobalSection
GlobalSection(BuildOrder) = postSolution
    0 = {17DC5F11-9B32-47FE-9F12-71923EC1C0DC}
EndGlobalSection
GlobalSection(DeploymentRoot) = postSolution
EndGlobalSection
EndGlobal
```

Here is a part of the content of .cls file:

```
VERSION 1.0 CLASS
BEGIN
  MultiUse = -1  'True
  Persistable = 0  'NotPersistable
  DataBindingBehavior = 0  'vbNone
  DataSourceBehavior  = 0  'vbNone
  MTSTransactionMode  = 0  'NotAnMTSObject
END
Attribute VB_Name = "EventClassModule"
Attribute VB_GlobalNameSpace = False
Attribute VB_Creatable = True
Attribute VB_PredeclaredId = False
Attribute VB_Exposed = True
Option Explicit
Option Base 1

Public WithEvents App As Application
Attribute App.VB_VarHelpID = -1
Public WithEvents Proj As Project
Attribute Proj.VB_VarHelpID = -1

Dim NewTaskIDs() As Long
Dim NumNewTasks As Long
```

Can somebody advise me the program was wrote by VB or VB.NET? and which Visual Studio can edit it? I tried VS 2008 but get an error which says: "Cannot be opened because its project type(.wip) is not supported by this version of Visual studio".

Thanks very much..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's VB6 with a [Visual Installer](http://www.devx.com/vb2themax/Article/19893) based setup project.

They are no longer supported.

Comment: There is no place that you can legally just download VS6 for free, you'll need to purchase it. It used to be available to MSDN subscribers, I would check there first. Otherwise you can still buy it online https://www.google.com/search?q=visual+basic+6&tbm=shop

Comment: There are other questions about where to get VB6. Briefly: Chris is correct. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1766514/any-cheap-or-free-ides-out-there-for-vb6-programming

Comment: The VB6 IDE is no longer supported. The runtime is still supported.

Comment: The VB6 runtime is even supported in Windows 8. See: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/ms788708

Comment: The .cls may be VB6, but that .sln is VB.NET, no?

Comment: Ah, they used Visual Studio .NET to build an install for a VB6 app?

Comment: I guess .sln should be solution file of Visual studio,  how could you think they used Visual Studio .NET to build an install for a VB6 app?