# Are there any free tools for developing VB.NET applications?

Tags: visual-studio-2010

Are there any free tools for developing VB.NET applications?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Any cheap or free IDE's out there for VB6 programming?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1766514/any-cheap-or-free-ides-out-there-for-vb6-programming)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Microsoft tools have express versions which are free:
http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/eng/products/visual-studio-express-products

Comment: Glad to hear.Is that product only going to be end after 30 days ? not application , correct ?

Comment: I'm going to develop one application using visual studio express products.Application not going to be expire on 30 days, correct ?

Comment: @user441978 No the application is not going to expire in 30 days, you need to register visual studio express with microsoft, but that is free.

Answer (score 2):

If you are not willing to go for microsoft product then here is an awesome product for you which is open source and much less in size:

It is called Sharp Develop:

http://www.icsharpcode.net/opensource/sd/ [Download and Info link]

Comment: And I think you must be knowing this already that express products of visual studio are free to use here is the link for visual studio 2010 express: http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/eng/downloads#d-2010-express

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft Visual Studio Community (Visual Studio Express) is a free and full-featured IDE for building apps for Web, Windows Store, Windows Desktop, and even Android and iOS using programming languages including C#, C++, HTML/JavaScript, and Visual Basic.

https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/products/visual-studio-express-vs.aspx

But its only licensed to use for academic/ research kind projects. See the terms:

https://www.visualstudio.com/support/legal/dn877550

A good free IDE is available from CodePlex, called SharpDevelop.
https://sharpdevelop.codeplex.com/releases/view/111370

But you still need to make sure the controls used in your projects are licenced.