# How do I configure eclipse IDE for VB6

Tags: eclipse, configuration, vb6

I just downloaded and "installed" (i.e. extracted) the latest eclipse:

Eclipse Standard/SDK

Version: Kepler Service Release 1
Build id: 20130919-0819

I want to import a VB6 project so I can navigate through it and analyse it (maybe eventually build it, but that is not essential). How do I do this?

I have looked at the preferences in under window-->prefs and looked through all the various options, but I can't see a way to set it up for *.bas files. Maybe I need a plugin or somthing? or perhaps there is a Eclipse for VB6 (like there is one for c/c++)?

Comment: Eclipse doesn't support VB6. http://stackoverflow.com/a/14360515/139010

Comment: @MattBall ahh...poo :( ... thanks for the answers and links :)

Comment: Most of the VB6 files are basically text, so you can examine them with a text editor. The only exceptions are the files for binary objects (form pictures etc in *.frx files). Apart from that, I'm sure you can download VB6 Pro from some abandonware site or something.

Comment: @Boann The options for downloading VB6 are discussed [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1766853/15639). It currently costs about £100 UK on e-Bay to buy a [legal VB6](http://www.ebay.co.uk/bhp/visual-basic-6-software) - the learning edition isn't useful. The high price is because it isn't abandonware. It isn't abandonware because if you have legacy VB6 to maintain [it is expensive to migrate it to .Net](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vb6-migration), so there is still a market for the VB6 IDE.