# Is it possible in Eclipse to define syntax highlighting for a language without resorting to Java programming?

Tags: eclipse, syntax-highlighting

I am looking for a way to [define some syntax coloring](http://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_How_do_I_provide_syntax_coloring_in_an_editor%3F) for a language in Eclipse. I only need to highlight certain sets of keywords, so the logic is trivial. So I would like to be able to define these in a plain definition file. Is there perhaps some Eclipse plugin which allows this, or is it possible out of the box?

Comment: Somewhat duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/746031/how-can-i-create-a-custom-eclipse-syntax-highlighter/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**[XText](http://www.eclipse.org/Xtext/)** is a more generic and complex solution, which will generate for you the code for a custom Editor able to offer the usual IDE features, that are derived from a grammar (your "plain definition file"), including.

- syntax coloring, *but also*
- model navigation (F3, etc.),
- code completion,
- outline view, and
- code templates.

Comment: XText is a very powerful tool to built Domain Specific Languages editors and code generators (with XTend) but it's not a generic colored editor.

Comment: I can't instal the eclipse extension. It gets stuck when requesting the add-on from the webiste for several minutes: http://prntscr.com/eqst7t

Comment: @kajacx That is possible:last time I used it was, as in this answer, seven years ago.

Comment: @kajacx That being said, http://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/eclipse-xtext is supposed to be compatible with the latest Eclipse distros. What version of Eclipse are you using?

Comment: I have Mars.2 Release (4.5.2), and now I get [this error](http://image.prntscr.com/image/4d8673280a6945469e3cf483dddc3dd3.png) when I try to install XPath.

Comment: @kajacx OK. It is best to ask a separate question.

Answer (score 1):

The [EclipseColorer](http://colorer.sourceforge.net/eclipsecolorer/index.html) plugin may fit the bill!

Comment: Not available since 4.x.x eclipse version

Answer (score 1):

It's a bit fiddly, but try http://gstaff.org/colorEditor/.

It uses the jEdit syntax highlighting files. So you need to create your highlighting file and add it to the jar in the plugin, as well as editing the catalog file in there to include it.

I used jEdit itself to test and debug my custom highlighting, rather than having to exit Eclipse, make the change and reload it each time.