# plugin for a new language

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I am developing a development tool for a new language. I can't say the details of the language because the organization applied for patent. I am new to `eclipse` and `plugin development`. how can I create a user interface which is similar to `cdt` or `jdt`. The first module I have to complete is UI development. Please help me to find some good source which give the `jdt ui` code.

now i need to change `file -> new` . when click on new it should give the option to create any type of file i.e. user defined file also can create

Comment: Too broad. Please be specific.

Comment: i need these things.. i dont want anything more then how can i ?

Comment: The JDT code is included with Eclipse if you install the `Eclipse SDK`, however this is extremely complex.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're new to plugin development, I'd strongly recommend taking a look at Xtext:

http://www.eclipse.org/Xtext/

**It is exactly what you are searching for**: you give it the BNF of your language, and it gives you an Eclipse build with an editor, syntax highlight, content assist, validation & quick fixes, outlines, etc. (Of course, this is a bit simplified description but that's the idea behind the project.)

Answer (score 0):

What you are asking for is very complex and quite a big task. I think you should start by creating a custom editor with syntax highlighting for your new language. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/746031/how-can-i-create-a-custom-eclipse-syntax-highlighter) may help you get started.

Comment: just help me to do one thing. when we run an eclipse plugin project it will shows a new eclipse instance under this file->new menu we have to create a sub menu that sub menu should provide the functionality to create a new file with user defined extension and save it in memory

Comment: will you please help me

Comment: **Do not start to implement "File -> New"**. Use Xtext as rlegendi suggests in [his answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21425216/3104218). Xtext will take care of "File -> New" and many other things. Creating an editor for you language with Xtext takes hours to weeks depending on how complex the language is. Creating an editor without Xtext takes you months. If it is not up to you to decide whether to use Xtext or not, talk to the person who can make the decision. Xtext saves you an enormous amount of time, especially if you're new to Eclipse development.

Comment: actually the problem is concern person told me to do this as an assignment, i mean this file - > new think. or do file -> new -> user defined file

Comment: @user3243181, @acanda; Creating a basic editor that shows syntax highlighting is fairly easy. There are several that you can subclass and reuse alot of code. But with that said, I agree, XText would be my first starting point as well.