# Is there VBA syntax highlighting for opening and closing loops and if statements?

Tags: vba, syntax, ms-word, vbe

Sorry if this has been asked before but I can't seem to find any information on this. I am working with VBA for automating word documents and I have this huge block of code with tons of "if else" statements, "do while" loops and "with" statements all nested together.

When I program using other languages and other IDE's, I can normally click the opening "if" or "while" bracket and get the highlighted closing bracket. This makes it a lot easier to keep track of everything. Is there anything close to this functionality in VBA for Word? I am going mad trying to keep track of everything!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure it has what you are looking for, but [Rubber duck for VBA](http://www.rubberduck-vba.com/) has some pretty awesome features to upgrade the VBA IDE.

---

EDIT:

Two more things to try:

[Smart Indenter](https://www.add-ins.com/macro-products-for-Microsoft-Excel/how-to-indent-vba-code/how-to-indent-vba-code.htm) - this one might actually help you more, as it creates intendation, thus helping to identify structures.

[MZ-Tools](http://www.mztools.com/index.aspx) - not free, but has a 30 day trial. (I haven't tried this one - report back if it is any good :) )

Comment: Thanks, I'll have to check it out when I leave work. I can't download software here,

Comment: Yeah well, I have it installed, and checked it, and can't seem to do what you are looking for. :( Sorry. Anyway, it is a very useful tool, making VBE a lot more powerful.

Comment: Bummer! Thanks for checking for me. I might try out Rubber Duck anyways.

Comment: @KurtLeadley I have added two more references to my answer. Smart Indenter might help you with your problem. It is still not exactly what you are looking for, but makes the code a lot more readable, and makes it a lot easier to find the end of an `If...End If` statement.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the [Eclipse Colorer plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53831524/1915920) which supports e.g. folding and if-then-else-end highlighting etc.:

[image]

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but this doesn't work inside the VBE IDE but in Eclipse, right? Unfortunately MS Office VBA is really only useful inside the VBE IDE...

Comment: Only Eclipse - right. For standard programming I would also not use the Eclipse IDE - right. But for version control, minor bugfixes, search/find/replace, renaming, documentation, analysis of existing code/libraries, source linking in issue tracking etc. it can be quite handy!